# misbehaving of shell "while read" loop, reading in wrong sequence

Tags: shell, loops

I have a script

```
index=0
while read line 
do  
  echo "read line is $line" 
  line=`echo ${line}|awk '{print $1}'`  

  index=$((index+1)) 

  if((index%2==0));then 
    echo "before continue line is $line"  
    continue 
  fi   

  echo "index is $index and now modify html page with $line" 
  ...
  ...
  done< infile
```

the content of infile is:

```
1OrMcP2CdV4 180 

1Wp33RG2XaA 180 

21zUUJ04ovI 180 

2pIqUhaDMLg 180 

2WRU4NUJSVc 180 
...
...
```

in the infile, there are alternate null lines, which are deliberately added by myself, why I did this, you can refer to http://goo.gl/K7g0m, which is another strange behavior of "while read" loop. Basically, the "read" can't read the even lines correctly, so I make the even lines as null lines.

I run the script and the output is:

```
read line is 1OrMcP2CdV4 180
index is 1 and now modify html page with 1OrMcP2CdV4


read line is 1Wp33RG2XaA 180
before continue line is 1Wp33RG2XaA


read line is 
index is 3 and now modify html page with 


read line is 21zUUJ04ovI 180
before continue line is 21zUUJ04ovI

read line is 
index is 5 and now modify html page with
```

so basically, it seems that the "while read loop" reads line in order: 1 3 2 5 4

then I modified the null line, like

```
1OrMcP2CdV4 180 
Axxx
1Wp33RG2XaA 180 
Axxx
21zUUJ04ovI 180 
Axxx 
2pIqUhaDMLg 180 
Axxx  
2WRU4NUJSVc 180 
...
..
```

the output is interesting:

```
read line is 1OrMcP2CdV4 180
index is 1 and now modify html page with 1OrMcP2CdV4

read line is xxx
before continue line is xxx


read line is 1Wp33RG2XaA 180
index is 3 and now modify html page with 1Wp33RG2XaA

read line is xxx
before continue line is xxx

read line is 21zUUJ04ovI
index is 5 and now modify html page with 21zUUJ04ovI 


read line is 21zUUJ04ovI 180
before continue line is 21zUUJ04ovI
```

OK, it reads in order now, but the even lines "Axxx" are read as "xxx"
and for first 20 lines, it seems in order
but then from time to time, the order is in a mess again!!
interesting and weird, isn't it?

what is wrong with this misbehaving? 
for the script, there are several background commands, like

```
firefox &
tcpdump &
```

and also like

```
sleep 5
```

for the details, you can refer to the above link, so there may be subprocess synchronization problems? but I don't think so.

this problem is really weird and I'm really at a loss on  how to deal with it!

Comment: My suspicion of the problem is actually that your infile's formatting is inconsistent with regard to new lines and "null" lines.

Comment: no, I tested it using a simple script while read line;do echo $line;done<infile, the output is as expected.

Comment: Something in your undisclosed code is consuming a line of input.

Comment: I have updated the results, I don't think the undisclosed code consumes a line of input, you can see the codes by following the url

Comment: Which shell are you using? Bash? Edit: Ok I saw the URL, you are using bash.

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Are you showing _all_ of you code and the _exact_ input you are using?

Comment: yes, just follow the link, you will see my code: http://goo.gl/Iwory

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the first field of every second line? Then I suggest something like:

```
while read id rest 
do
     # here code to process id
     #  .....
     read again # skip every other line
done
```

By the way: what was the initial value of `index` in your code?

Comment: the initial value of index is 0. I used your "read again". The result is similar, when the null line is changed to a non-null string, it can reads in order, otherwise, it is in a mess. This is really weird!